# Where to buy non-kindle-format (epub,azw) e-books which look like the printed books?

Tags: books

If I want to buy e-copy of academic books, most of the publishers (Oxford, Cambridge, etc.) direct to amazon store or allow epub version. However, I do not want the e-pub or other formats (e.g. azw) as the ebook in this format does not have the actual pagination and format of the printed copy.

So, is there a store or place where I can buy the e-copy of the book (preferably in pdf format) which actually looks like the printed copy (having the actual page numbers and format/style of the printed copy)?

I am aware that some of the kindle books do come with both "locations" and "actual page numbers" to avoid the above problem. However, this is feature is not available for the majority of the books (as I open the sample version and check). Also, I miss the style/formatting of the printed book.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem. For Springer, I usually buy at its website, where you can find the PDF version. For Oxford and Cambridge, when I cannot find a decent Kindle version, I usually buy at [ebooks](https://www.ebooks.com).

However, for ebooks.com:

1. The number of available titles is limited, and I couldn't find titles that according to the publishers should be available as e-books.
2. The PDF is DRM-protected, which is an annoyance.

Comment: (+1) Thank you! Having published a book, I have several hardcopies, but have wanted a pdf version for ease of searching. All I could find was the epub, which I despise. Now I just have to decide whether or not to cough up $140 for my own book.

Comment: Massimo -- thanks for the suggestion about ebooks. When i googled for ebooks in general, I did come across this store. The PDF being DRM protected is a problem since I use Linux and it is not straightforward to use Adobe Digital here :(

Comment: @Varun With Calibre, which is also available for Linux, you can easily remove it ;-)

Comment: Lovely! Let me try that. Thanks!

Comment: @Varun After the Calibre installation, there is a plug in you have to add. Once you added it, it removes automatically the DRM whenever you load a book in Calibre.